# Relating two independent keys

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

Say I have two types of IDs, `entityID` and `linkID`.

These are used to refer to different types of objects and the IDs themselves are of different (non-convertible) types*. Each ID is unique within its type.

Each `Entity` corresponds to a `Link` which is stored elsewhere. I therefore want to be able to access one based on the other. To do this, I want to be able to convert from one ID type to the other.

How I would normally associate two differing types like this is with an `std::map<id, value>`. However, this limits searching to by `key`, and therefore only allows one-way conversion.

What I could do is create an `std::set<std::pair<entityID, linkID>>`. This ensures fast conversion from `entityID` to `linkID` when searching by `std::pair::first`, with reasonable time when searching by `std::pair::second` using `std::find_if`.

Again, this doesn't seem like a clean solution and isn't obvious to anyone reading the code. While, as I understand it, it's impossible to have a container sorted by two keys, I'm wondering if there's a more convenient way of storing this relationship.

---

*In case it matters, the types of the IDs are`unsigned short` and a `struct{unsigned int, unsigned short}`.

---

**Edit**
The [boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/introduction.html) as mentioned by [sharth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47453/sharth) in the comments is what I was looking for.

Comment: [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) is a great solution to this.

Comment: @sharth Indeed that's exactly what I'm looking for. My vocabulary was unable to produce a suitable google search, though. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement clearly, then you want to have a pair of entityID and linkID. In addition to this, you want to have some fast search algorithm based on entityID and linkID both.

There are 3 solutions to this:

1) Use 2 maps one with entityID as key and other with linkID as key.

2) Use multi-key map like one from Boost Multi-Index library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

3) Use Boost::Bimap which stands for bi-directional map.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

Please let me know if it does not solve your problem.

Comment: Yes! `boost::bimap` does fit what I'm trying to do. If possible, I'd like to use the STL, however. Can you explain how your first solution works? Also, feel free to edit the question to make it more general/more clear if you can.